# SQL Server 2012 - login por autenticação do SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Na instalação eu coloquei uma senha e a anotei. Quando vou fazer o login por autenticação do SQL server o campo login está em branco, só anotei a senha não sei o login. Tentei o mesmo que do autenticação do Windows, mas não deu certo. Como faço para ver qual é o login? Outra pergunta: tem como alterar o login e senha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução aqui: http://pt.wikihow.com/Redefinir-a-Senha-de-Administrador-do-Sistema-no-SQL-Server

No meu caso, entrei com a autenticação do Windows, depois fui na pasta "segurança - logins" e criei um novo; também vi que meu login era "sa".